# Socket.io - Cannot send messages to rooms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, express, socket.io

```
socket.on('join room', function (data) {
    var room = data.room;
    var msg = "<span style='color:darkgreen;'>" + data.user + " has joined chat.</span>";

    socket.join(room, function () {
        console.log(socket.id + " now in rooms ", socket.rooms);
    });

    io.in(room).emit('system message', msg);
});
```

If I change `io.in(room)` to `socket.broadcast` the system message goes through. For whatever reason though, it will not send messages to specific rooms, it just does nothing, no errors either. Any ideas what's going wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried moving the `io.in(room).emit('system message', msg);` inside the `socket.join(room, function(){ // move it here ...}` callback?

Comment: Just did what you suggested but no avail. It didn't change anything.

Comment: Here is my index.js and index.html code http://plnkr.co/edit/pig8u4SwuigRN3ej3KLm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the code above is on back-end, correct?

Try the following, adapt it with your needs if necessary:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    // You should expect ONLY one user connected, 
    // > otherwise, you're creating multiple sessions :)
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('join room', function (data) {
        var room = data.room;
        console.log('Room: ', room);
        var msg = "<span style='color:darkgreen;'>" + data.user + " has joined chat.</span>";

        socket.join(room); // No callback needed
        console.log(socket.id + " now in rooms ", socket.rooms);
        io.to(room).emit('system message', msg);
        // Change it to io.to(room)

    });
});
```

I noticed you're asking to join on front-end using:

```
$(".channelChange").click( function(evt) {
    var socket = io();
    $("#messages").html("");
    evt.stopPropagation();
    if($.inArray(evt.currentTarget, $(this).children())){
        console.log("user moved to " + evt.currentTarget.id);
    }
    setCookie("currentRoom", evt.currentTarget.id, 1);
    $(".roomName").html("<span class='3Dtext'>" + evt.currentTarget.id + "</span>");
    $("#enter-sound").get(0).play();
    getMessages(getCookie("currentRoom"));
    // Here you ask to join room
    socket.emit('join room', { user: getCookie("username"), room: getCookie("currentRoom") });
})
```

And receiving the *system message* on:

```
   $(function(){
        var socket = io();
        socket.on('system message', function(msg) {
            alert("test");
            $('#messages').append($('<div class="systemMessage">').html(msg));
            var height = $("#messages")[0].scrollHeight;
            $.mobile.silentScroll(height);
    });
```

The main problem as you'll see, is that you're calling `io()` everytime, this created different sessions, 
 1. Session one joins a room
 2. A different session will await for *system message*

Hence, you need a single `io()` session, a quick work arround is to make a self invoking function:

```
const setIo = (function (){
        const _io = io();
        return () => _io;
    })()
```

And then **Replace all io()** declarations to: `var socket = setIo();`

such as:

```
$(".channelChange").click( function(evt) {
    var socket = setIo();
    $("#messages").html("");
    evt.stopPropagation();
```

This will create a single io() session instead of different ones, and re-use it everytime you call `setIo()`

You'll eventually see the alert pop up:

[image]

Comment: I think I might see what's happening. This is what the `console.log` returns for showing what rooms the socket is in: 
`gp187Mc6-75VmnTsAAAf now in rooms  { 'gp187Mc6-75VmnTsAAAf': 'gp187Mc6-75VmnTsAAAf',
  'General Chat': 'General Chat' }`

Comment: Yes, just found out what the problem is, got it working, give me 5 mins

Comment: The problem was you were calling io() many times, each call will create a new socket session, thus, they logic on each event was independent. Used a self-invoking function to work around it.

Comment: It worked! I never would have thought of that being new to socket.io. Thank you so much! Now I just need to play around with the design part so it appends at the bottom. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

`socket.join()` is asynchronous.  It has not completed yet when you're trying to send to the room, so no message goes to that socket because it isn't yet in the room.  So, change this:

```
socket.join(room, function () {
    console.log(socket.id + " now in rooms ", socket.rooms);
});

io.in(room).emit('system message', msg);
```

to this:

```
socket.join(room, function () {
    console.log(socket.id + " now in rooms ", socket.rooms);
    io.in(room).emit('system message', msg);
});
```

So, in this new version you're not sending to the room until AFTER the `.join()` has completed rather than before.

You can see a similar example right in the [socket.io doc here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/docs/API.md#socketjoinroom-callback).